# How to store each user's request IPs and Agent in Laravel log

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-6

Currently using `Exceptions/Handler.php`, I can log all types of errors with all details of Users.

But how to log all requests data, and through which file?

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Exceptions;
    
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
    use Exception;
    use Throwable;
    use Request;
    use Log;
    
    .....
        public function report(Exception $e)
        {
    
            Log::info($e->getMessage(),
                [
    
                    'url' => Request::url(),
                    'all' => getallheaders(),
                    'Referer' => Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
                ]);
            $error = 
            [
                'url' => Request::url(),
                'all' => getallheaders(), 
                'Referer' => Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
            ];
    
             $message = $error['url'] . "\n" . json_encode($error, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                    \Log::info($message);
            return parent::report($e);
        }
```

....

Answer (score 2):

you can log all data for example in middleware which will run for each request.

Create middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware LogRequestMiddleware
```

Your middleware is saved to app/Http/Middleware/LogRequestMiddleware.php

In your middleware rewrite handle method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
   Log::info('This is my log', ['request' => $request->all()])

   return $next($request);
}
```

And at the top of the file add:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

When you want to register global middleware for every request you can do it like this in your Kernel.php file:

```
    protected $middleware = [
        LogRequestMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Where LogRequestMiddleware is your middleware :)

Comment: function in Kernel.php?

Comment: In your Kernel.php you will register this middleware to `protected $middleware` array. I will update answer for you to see how.

Comment: Where to put the Function, I put the function but it throws 500 error.

Comment: The function ```handle``` should be in your new middleware. You can call it `LogRequestMiddleware`

Comment: Target class [App\Http\LogRequestMiddleware] does not exist.

Comment: you have to import App\Http\Middleware\LogRequestMiddleware not App\Http\LogRequestMiddleware

Comment: @JohnLobo Call to a member function send() on string

Comment: I added in protected $routeMiddleware and it worked

Comment: @Amit do not edit the original answer with what worked for you, as your edit is another type of solution, so your change is too drastic even for 1 line, so post as new answer and mark this answer as correct or yours but do not edit this with a drastic change as that was not the original answer's author intent.